# Pass values to previous view controller in a navigationviewcontroller stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

In UINavigationViewController, if I wanna pass values from one controller to next, just call `- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` , but what should I do if I wanna pass values from one viewController to previous viewController

Comment: You can use `NSNotificationCenter` to post objects in the viewDidDisappear method

Comment: Yes,viewDidDisappear,thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember running across this same issue a few projects back. I can't find the my code to answer this question, but I did find a few tutorials.

http://prateekvjoshi.com/2014/02/16/ios-app-passing-data-between-view-controllers/

http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/torrey-betts/archive/2014/05/29/passing-data-between-view-controllers-ios-obj-c.aspx

Comment: the OP key question is to **when** call those delegate methods (tutorials say nothing about it in `UINavigationController` case)

Comment: both tutorials mention to use delegate, it's kinda difficult but will be work, thanks very much

Comment: crap, I thought when current viewcontroller is pop out of stack, there would be a delegate method callback,but I did not find it

Comment: check `UINavigationControllerDelegate`

Comment: just write it in viewDidDisappear

Answer (score 0):

and hence the concept of delegate came forth from segues.
Basically Segues are transition from one view to another but the child view is over the parent view, (inside a stack) so the parent view is still loaded.
So if u put segues everywhere and pass values between them then objects will keep on be creating and stored inside a stack and thus the cycle carries on.

So delegates was introduced.
Delegate is a method by which a child view controller(the later one) sends information using the inbuild delegate methods or self created protocol methods to the Previous view controller(the first one).

Here the  one sending the information(later view) declares a delegate object, and a delegate method.
Which is then implemented by the recieving class(first view). So even after the later view is popped from the stack, the information is sent back to the root view by the delegate method.

Go through the documentation, its given in a more appropriate way 
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Set previous view controller as delegate of current view controller and pass any values you want. This is standard approach.